# Saving Multiple Images in Form Wizard Django and ManyToMany Fields not Working

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, django-formwizard

I am working on a project in Django that I have to use a Form Wizard. Part of the requirement is to save multiple images in one of the form steps, and to save a many to many field, which are not working as expected. Let me first share my code before explaining the problem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from location_field.models.plain import PlainLocationField
from PIL import Image
from slugify import slugify
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from listing_admin_data.models import (Service, SubscriptionType, PropertySubCategory,
        PropertyFeatures, VehicleModel, VehicleBodyType, VehicleFuelType,
        VehicleColour, VehicleFeatures, BusinessAmenities, Currency, EventsType
    )
import datetime
from django_google_maps.fields import AddressField, GeoLocationField


def current_year():
    return datetime.date.today().year

def max_value_current_year(value):
    return MaxValueValidator(current_year())(value)


class Listing(models.Model):
    listing_type_choices = [('P', 'Property'), ('V', 'Vehicle'), ('B', 'Business/Service'), ('E', 'Events')]

    listing_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    listing_type = models.CharField(choices=listing_type_choices, max_length=1, default='P')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, blank=True)
    address = AddressField(max_length=100)
    geolocation = GeoLocationField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expires_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True
    )
    listing_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='list_owner'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.listing_title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.listing.listing_title
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "listings_pics/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class ListingImages(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Listing Images')
    main_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Listing Images"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title} Image'


class Subscriptions(models.Model):
    subscription_type = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscription_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subscription_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    subscribed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    listing_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Listing)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subscriptions"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title} Subscription'


class Property(models.Model):
    sale_hire_choices = [('S', 'Sale'), ('R', 'Rent')]
    fully_furnished_choices = [('Y', 'Yes'), ('N', 'No')]

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(PropertySubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_sale_rent = models.CharField(choices=sale_hire_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    bedrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    bathrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    land_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available_from = models.DateField()
    car_spaces = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    fully_furnished = models.CharField(choices=fully_furnished_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    desc = models.TextField()
    property_features = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyFeatures)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Properties"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    sale_hire_choices = [('S', 'Sale'), ('H', 'Hire')]
    transmission_choices = [('A', 'Automatic'), ('M', 'Manual')]
    drive_choices = [('L', 'Left'), ('R', 'Right')]
    condition_choices = [('L', 'Locally Used'), ('F', 'Foreign Used'), ('N', 'Brand New')]
    interior_choices = [('C', 'Cloth'), ('L', 'Leather'), ('O', 'Other')]

    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    for_sale_hire = models.CharField(choices=sale_hire_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    year_of_manufacture = models.IntegerField(_('year'), validators=[MinValueValidator(1900), max_value_current_year])
    engine_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    transmission = models.CharField(choices=transmission_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    drive = models.CharField(choices=drive_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    current_millage = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    condition = models.CharField(choices=condition_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    interior = models.CharField(choices=interior_choices, max_length=1, default=None)
    number_of_doors = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    body_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleBodyType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fuel_type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleFuelType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour = models.ForeignKey(VehicleColour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle_features = models.ManyToManyField(VehicleFeatures)
    asking_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'


class Business(models.Model):
    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
    website_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    business_amenities = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessAmenities)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Businesses"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing.listing_title}'


class Event(models.Model):
    listing = models.OneToOneField(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventsType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    overview = models.TextField()
    entry_fee = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.event_title}'
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
import datetime
from .models import Listing, Property, Vehicle, Business, ListingImages, Event
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import (
        DatePickerInput, TimePickerInput, DateTimePickerInput,
        MonthPickerInput, YearPickerInput
    )
from listing_admin_data.models import (
        PropertyFeatures, VehicleFeatures, BusinessAmenities
    )
from django_google_maps.widgets import GoogleMapsAddressWidget


def year_choices():
    return [(r,r) for r in range(1900, datetime.date.today().year+1)]

def current_year():
    return datetime.date.today().year

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class ListingDetails(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['listing_title', 'address', 'geolocation']
        widgets = {
            "address": GoogleMapsAddressWidget,
        }

class PropertyDetails1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['sub_category', 'for_sale_rent', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms',
            'rooms', 'land_size', 'available_from', 'car_spaces', 'fully_furnished',
            'desc', 'currency', 'price'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'available_from': DatePickerInput(),
        }

class PropertyDetails2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['property_features']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(PropertyDetails2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["property_features"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["property_features"].queryset = PropertyFeatures.objects.all()

class ListingImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image_url = forms.ImageField(label='Listing Image',
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        required=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ListingImages
        fields = ['image_url']

class VehicleDetails1(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    year_of_manufacture = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, choices=year_choices, initial=current_year())
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['for_sale_hire', 'make', 'model', 'year_of_manufacture',
            'current_millage', 'body_type', 'transmission', 'condition',
            'asking_price'
        ]

class VehicleDetails2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['engine_capacity', 'description', 'drive', 'interior',
            'number_of_doors', 'fuel_type', 'colour', 'vehicle_features'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(VehicleDetails2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["vehicle_features"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["vehicle_features"].queryset = VehicleFeatures.objects.all()

class BusinessDetails1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['service', 'business_name', 'slogan', 'website_address', 'email_address', 'contact', 'desc']

class BusinessDetails2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['business_amenities']

class EventDetails1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['event_title', 'event_type', 'event_date', 'end_date', 'overview', 'entry_fee']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import os
from .forms import (ListingDetails, ListingImagesForm,
        PropertyDetails1, PropertyDetails2, VehicleDetails1,
        VehicleDetails2, BusinessDetails1, BusinessDetails2, EventDetails1
    )
from django.views.generic import (
    DetailView, ListView
)
from .models import ListingImages, Listing, Property, Vehicle, Business, Event
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.forms.models import construct_instance
from .filters import PropertyFilter, VehicleFilter, BusinessFilter, EventFilter

class PropertyView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "listings/create_listing.html"
    form_list = [ListingDetails, PropertyDetails1, PropertyDetails2, ListingImagesForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        listing_instance = Listing()
        property_instance = Property()
        listing_image_instance = ListingImages()
        listing_instance.created_by = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_owner = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_type = 'P'
        for form in form_list:
            listing_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            property_instance = construct_instance(form, property_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            listing_image_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_image_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        listing_instance.save()
        property_instance.listing = listing_instance
        property_instance.save()
        # listing_image_instance.listing = listing_instance
        # listing_image_instance.save()
        for image in listing_image_instance:
            image.listing = listing_instance # saved above
            image.save()
        return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
        # return render(self0.request, 'done.html', {
        #     'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        # })

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class VehicleView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "listings/create_listing.html"
    form_list = [ListingDetails, VehicleDetails1, VehicleDetails2, ListingImagesForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        listing_instance = Listing()
        vehicle_instance = Vehicle()
        listing_image_instance = ListingImages()
        listing_instance.created_by = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_owner = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_type = 'V'
        for form in form_list:
            listing_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            vehicle_instance = construct_instance(form, vehicle_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            listing_image_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_image_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        listing_instance.save()
        vehicle_instance.listing = listing_instance
        vehicle_instance.save()
        listing_image_instance.listing = listing_instance
        listing_image_instance.save()
        # for li_obj in listing_image_instances:
        #     li_obj.listing = listing_instance # saved above
        #     li_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
        # return render(self0.request, 'done.html', {
        #     'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        # })

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class BusinessView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "listings/create_listing.html"
    form_list = [ListingDetails, BusinessDetails1, BusinessDetails2, ListingImagesForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        listing_instance = Listing()
        business_instance = Business()
        listing_image_instance = ListingImages()
        listing_instance.created_by = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_owner = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_type = 'B'
        for form in form_list:
            listing_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            business_instance = construct_instance(form, business_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            listing_image_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_image_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        listing_instance.save()
        business_instance.listing = listing_instance
        business_instance.save()
        listing_image_instance.listing = listing_instance
        listing_image_instance.save()
        # for li_obj in listing_image_instances:
        #     li_obj.listing = listing_instance # saved above
        #     li_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
        # return render(self0.request, 'done.html', {
        #     'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        # })

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class EventView(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "listings/create_listing.html"
    form_list = [ListingDetails, EventDetails1, ListingImagesForm]
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'media'))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        listing_instance = Listing()
        event_instance = Event()
        listing_image_instance = ListingImages()
        listing_instance.created_by = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_owner = self.request.user
        listing_instance.listing_type = 'E'
        for form in form_list:
            listing_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            event_instance = construct_instance(form, event_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
            listing_image_instance = construct_instance(form, listing_image_instance, form._meta.fields, form._meta.exclude)
        listing_instance.save()
        event_instance.listing = listing_instance
        event_instance.save()
        listing_image_instance.listing = listing_instance
        listing_image_instance.save()
        # for li_obj in listing_image_instances:
        #     li_obj.listing = listing_instance # saved above
        #     li_obj.save()
        return HttpResponse('data saved successfully')
        # return render(self0.request, 'done.html', {
        #     'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        # })

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except KeyError:
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And here is the template used by the views

create_listing.html

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<!-- necessary for date picker -->
<!-- {% block extra_css %}
{{ form.media.css }}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
{{ form.media.js }}
{% endblock %} -->
<!-- end date picker -->
{% block content %}

    <!-- ============================ Page Title  Start================================== -->
    <div class="page-title image-title" style="background-image:url('/static/base/assets/img/banner-4.jpg');">
      <div class="finding-overlay op-70"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-title-wrap">
        <h1>Submit Your Listing</h1>
        <p><a href="#" class="theme-cl">Home</a> <span class="current-page active">Add Your listing</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ============================ Page Title End ================================== -->

    <!-- =========================== Add Form Start ============================================ -->
        <section>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
            <form class="add-listing-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <!-- general information -->
                            <div class="tr-single-box">
                                <div class="tr-single-header">
                                    <h4><i class="ti-medall-alt"></i> Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</h4>
                                </div>
                <div class="tr-single-body">

                    {{ wizard.management_form }}

                    {{ form|crispy }}

                                </div>

              </div>

              {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-around pb-5">
                  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">First Step</button>
                  <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">Previous Step</button>
              </div>
              {% endif %}

              <button class="btn btn-primary full-width" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

{% endblock content %}
```

I am trying to implement the first class in the view, which are essentially similar for the rest of the classes that are saving the data. This part is giving me an error:

```
for image in listing_image_instance:
    image.listing = listing_instance # saved above
    image.save()
```

The error that I am getting is: `'ListingImages' object is not iterable`. The line pointed to is line 40 in `views.py` which is essentially the for loop above. Is there something that I am forgetting to make the `ListingImages` model submitted via the form iterable?

Another problem is that even though data is saved to the `Property` model, its `ManyToMany` field is not saved dispite data being submitted from the form. The field in question is this: `property_features = models.ManyToManyField(PropertyFeatures)`. What should I add in the code to ensure that this data is saved as expected?

Comment: There's *far* too much code here. But why would you think ListingImages should be iterable? It's a single instance, why do you want to iterate over it?

Comment: I am uploading several images, and I am want to save all of them. How should I handle that? I got the for loop from another code online and tried it but its not working. I can actually upload several images on the template but it is not working on the view.

Comment: Where are you uploading several images? You have a single ListingImagesForm in your form list, and that form only contains a single image field.

Comment: How should I handle that? Kindly guide me on how I should code my form to take in multiple images.